# Concatenating two data-frames having same number of rows in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am taking data from two different excel files as shown below,

```
df = pd.read_excel('abc.xlsx')
```

I'm extracting particular data from above data frame named df as shown below,

```
df1 = df[df['COMPTYPE'].astype(str).str.contains('MCCB|ACB|Contactor', regex=True)]
```

after that I've another data-frame named df2 as below,

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('inputfile.xlsx')
```

The df has 49 rows, df1 and df2 have 31 rows. I'm concatenating the df1 and df2 on axis=1 as below,

```
data = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
```

So here I expected that the final data frame "data" would have 31 rows however I'm getting 43 rows, apparently, df1 has some empty rows that I'm unable to detect and those empty rows are getting added to the final data frame while performing the pd.concat() operation hence the 43 rows instead of 31 rows.
Following images will show you how data is in excel file,
 [abc.xlsx file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7y6k.png)
[inputfile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbCdp.png)
Kindly help.

Comment: You can try to drop the empty rows before concatenating them in new dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
newdf = pd.concat([df2.reset_index(drop=True),df1.reset_index(drop=Tru‌​e)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, Mayank for your response. However, it's not working. df1 does not have any empty rows. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Okay, but in your question, you have written that some empty rows are appending to the final data. That's why I suggested it.

Comment: Could you please try this? newdf = pd.concat([df2.reset_index(drop=True),df1.reset_index(drop=Tru‌​e)], axis=1)